# cmake helper to create <package>_ROOT variables from local libs

Tags: cmake

We have a big project with many modules (shared libs). They have no static dependencies and work more like plugins. We want the build system to be able to use find_package(modA) when building a specific executable (exeA). We also don't want the project files generated to include every module (which will be hard to handle in VisualStudio etc), so it should just include (add_library) the modules needed for the executable built by a specific CMakeLists.txt (exeA).
One way to do this would be to use a helper function to find all Config.cmake files from the project root folder and either add them to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or generate _ROOT variables. Then the executable CMakeLists.txt could just do find_package(modX) on any dependencies.

Q: Is there any way to locate all *Config.cmake files in a folder recursively and add them to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or _ROOT? Or any helper (except file(GLOB_RECURSE)) that could help in locating these paths that could be used in a more specific helper macro.

Comment: What is wrong with `file(GLOB_RECURSE)`? Yes, globbing is not recommended. But what you want **is** a globbing, whatever function you would use. (Actually, globbing is not recommended for locate source files with code. Using globbing for other artifacts doesn't fit into this "non-recommendation".)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with globbing, I just wondered if maybe there already was some helpers in cmake that could do this, or help converting the /path/to/xx/cmake/xxConfig.cmake paths to xx_ROOT=/path/to/xx/cmake

Comment: I don't think that CMake favors such automatic filling of search paths for `find_package`, so they unlikely have a helper for this task. Just use `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` and appropriate `string` functions. This should be simple.